# Problem using publishUserAction method to post to profile

Tags: php, sdk, gigya

I am using gigya php sdk, It works well I am able to post to user's wall or profile using socialise.setStatus method but I am have problems when I try to use the publishuseraction method. I get an error Invalid request signature.

```
$method = "socialize.publishUserAction";

$request = new GSRequest($apiKey,$secretKey,$method);

$userAction = new GSDictionary("{\"title\":\"This is my title\", \"userMessage\":\"This is a user message\", \"description\":\"This is a description\",      \"linkBack\":\"http://google.com\", \"mediaItems\":[{\"src\":\"http://www.f2h.co.il/logo.jpg\", \"href\":\"http://www.f2h.co.il\",\"type\":\"image\"}]}"); 

$request->setParam("userAction", $userAction);  

$request->setParam("uid", $userUID);  

$response = $request->send();

if($response->getErrorCode()==0){ 
    echo "Success";   
} else { 
    echo ("Error: " . $response->getErrorMessage());
}
```

UPDATED AFTER USING $response->getLog()

```
apiMethod=socialize.publishUserAction
apiKey=correct_api_key
params={"userAction":{},uid":"MY_UID","format":"json","httpStatusCodes":"false"}
URL=http://socialize.gigya.com/socialize.publishUserAction    postData=uid=urlencoded(MY_UID)&format=json&httpStatusCodes=false&apiKey=correct_api_key×tamp=1296229876&nonce=1.29622987636E%2B12&sig=HEdzy%2BzxetV8QvTDjdsdMWh0%2Fz8%3D
server= web504
```

I used both put method

```
$userAction = new GSDictionary();

$userAction->put("title", "This is my title");
$userAction->put("userMessage", "This is my user message");
$userAction->put("description", "This is my description");
$userAction->put("linkBack", "http://google.com");

$mediaItems = array();
$mediaItems[0] = new GSDictionary("{\"src\":\"http://www.f2h.co.il/logo.jpg\", \"href\":\"http://www.f2h.co.il\",\"type\":\"image\"}");
```

& JSON method

```
$userAction = new GSDictionary("{\"title\":\"This is my title\", \"userMessage\":\"This is a user message\", \"description\":\"This is a description\", 
     \"linkBack\":\"http://google.com\", \"mediaItems\":[ {\"src\":\"http://www.f2h.co.il/logo.jpg\", \"href\":\"http://www.f2h.co.il\",\"type\":\"image\"}]}");
```

I get the same error. And User action is empty using both methods. I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling getLog() for a bit more information about the error:

```
if($response->getErrorCode()==0){ 
    echo "Success";   
} else { 
    echo ("Error: " . $response->getErrorMessage());
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($response->getLog());
    print "</pre>";
}
```

Also, are you able to run getUserInfo w/ the SDK? This is a simple test that also requires a signature. Use the example on the **[PHP SDK](http://developers.gigya.com/030_Server_SDKs/PHP)** page (about 1/2 way down).

Comment: Thanks. I did follow your instructions and tried the getUserInfo it works fine. I am able to get user's details. Then, I did try to publish to user's wall after the updating code. Still same error Invalid Request Signature. In the log

Comment: I find the userAction to be empty using both methods. I have updated the log and my userActions in the question. I appreciate your help. Thanks again.

Comment: Finally got it to work. But I am not able to add media items with image or videos etc., Error: Invalid parameter value "errorDetails": "Invalid argument: missing 'type' field in media item" I have the type field. I appreciate any help.